# How to get the nodal raw numbers (from all the trees for a particula test vector) from which random forest calculates the prediction in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to predict a distribution rather than a single number using random forest regression in R. To do this, I'd like to get all the *numbers* from which random forest calculates (averages) the predicted value for a particular test vector. How can I get this done?

To be specific,

I'm not growing each tree to its full size, but limiting the size using nodesize parameter. In this case, I'm interested not in the prediction of each tree in the forest (which is given by setting the predict.all to TRUE) , but all the data points from which this prediction is calculated; that is all the data points from the node on which a new observation lands on, for  all the trees in the forest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The function `predict.randomForest` has a boolean parameter `predict.all` exactly for this purpose.

```
library("randomForest")
rf = randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris)
?predict.randomForest
allpred = predict(rf, newdata = iris, predict.all = TRUE)
```

Now, the `allpred$individual` is a matrix, where columns correspond to individual decision trees

Comment: What if I'm not growing each tree to its full size, but limiting the size using nodesize parameter? In this case, I'm interested not in the  prediction of each tree, but all the data points from which this prediction is calculated; that is all the data points from the terminal nodes of all the trees in the forest.